# Visual Studio Store Apps

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

So recently I've begun learning C# from this man's [video series.](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-2-Exercise-Writing-your-First-Windows-Phone-8-1-App) Right now I have Visual Studio 2013 (Community edition), and in his video he's using a subcategory called "Store Apps." My problem is that in the current version of Visual Studio I'm using, it doesn't acquire this subcategory. Anyway on how I may obtain it?

Thank you for your help.

Regards,

Saroekin.

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio Update 2 installed?  On the page you linked to it mentions that you need this installed to obtain the correct tooling in VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK installed as he suggested, and make sure that you also have Visual Studio Update 2 installed.

Comment from the video description:

> Note: Before we get started, make sure that you already have the
>   Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 installed, which will include the Windows
>   Phone 8.1 Tooling, like we talked about in the previous lesson. If you
>   already have that installed, then we're ready to move forward.

Comment: Alright, I appreciate the response. I have Visual Studio Update 2 installed, though how would I install/unpack the "Windows Phone 8.1 SDK"? Or is it when I download it, it's automatically added to Visual Studio?

Comment: It should be automatically installed into VS.

Comment: Other option is to install VS Express for Windows instead: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx